# AngularJS ng-repeat display specific item first

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using angular js ng-repeat and I want to show specific element first

For example I have this object

```
$scope.user = {
    age: {
        display: "Age",
        val: "21" 
    },
    firstName: {
        display: "First Name",
        val: "John" 
    },
    lastName: {
        display: "Last Name",
        val: "Smith" 
    },
}
```

And using ng-repeat like this.

```
<tr ng-repeat = "(key, value) in user">
    <td ng-model = "user[key].display"></td>
    <td ng-model = "user[key].val"></td>
</tr>
```

If I use ng-repeat, it shows age, firstName and lastName, but I want to show firstName in ng-repeat first.

Thank you.

Comment: have you tried changing to firsName be first?

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat  you can use a track by option. 
and then just an extra key value to be the index or key you wan't to order by

Comment: It is because when I get information from server, it must contain a lot of data, I don`t know what I will get, but I want to show firstName first and then show other data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no ordering in js objects. But you can extract the firstName and do the rest after:

```
<tr>
  <td ng-model = "user[firstName].display></td>
  <td ng-model = "user[firstName].value></td>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat = "(key, value) in user" ng-if="key!='firstName'">
  <td ng-model = "user[key].display"></td>
  <td ng-model = "user[key].val"></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Someone posted the option of specifying the order in the object. While this is a valid option in terms of result, I'd not recommend it, as it means putting view logic in the data layer!

Answer (score 1):

As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order), you cannot specify the order of keys in javascript. You have to restructure your data to an array if you want to guarantee a certain order.